# Counting of unicode characters in my Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have customers name in a table as following BÝRLEÞÝK F
I have many such records in the table. I want to count all such records in my table .
I tried below query but to no use

```
Select Count(*) From customer Where Length(name)!= asciistr(Length(name))
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not Len(name)?

Comment: my oracle is UTF8 enabled. So  length(name)= asciistr(length(name)). Am I right?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `length(asciistr(name))` instead of  `asciistr(Length(name))`. `asccistr('6')` will return `6`

Comment: I tried this too, doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Where LengthC(name)!= Length(asciistr(name))
```